# Lazy Image Load: [NSURL URLWithString:<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>] returns nil in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, lazy-loading

I have images in my app's documents directory but I want to load images in tableView as Lazy Image Load.

So I want to use

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Now, this `[NSURL URLWithString:<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>"]` returns **nil**.

What should be done?

**EDIT:**

```
NSString *FundNames = [[array1 objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"FundName"];
        NSDate *dates=[NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *ab = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        //[ab setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        [ab setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString *dateStr = [ab stringFromDate:dates];

    NSString *imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.png",FundNames,dateStr]; 
    //NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [self getImagePath];
    NSLog(@"Image Path : %@",documentsDirectory);
    NSError *error1;
    NSString *filepath1;
    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error1];
    if (files == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading contents of documents directory: %@", [error1 localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSLog(@"FileName: %@",imageName);

    BOOL success = NO;

    for (NSString *file in files)
    {
        NSLog(@"file in Files is %@",file);
        if([file isEqualToString:imageName])
        {
            filepath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
            NSLog(@"Full Path :%@",filepath1);
            success = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filepath1];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newfund.png"]];
```

Here , **filepath1** is equal to `<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>`

Comment: [NSURL URLWithString:<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>"] Are you sure that " is there?

Comment: @7KV7: Thanks for the input. Yeah I am sure that file exists at `<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>` and also I am sure that I use `[NSURL URLWithString:<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>"]`. What could be wrong?

Comment: Why is that " there after <imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>"? Is it necessary?

Comment: @7KV7: Thats just a typing mistake..Sorry. Didn't notice that. What could be done?

Comment: Is it necessary that you want to use NSURL or will it be ok if you try using imageWithContentsOfFile:

Comment: @7KV7: But using `imageWithContentsOfFile` how can I implement Lazy Table Image Load?

Comment: I have provided an answer. See if it makes sense. I am not sure about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>"]` instead of `[NSURL URLWithString:<imagePathFromMyDocumentsDirectory>"]`

Comment: Thanks Zaky. I will try that soon.

Comment: If I am not wrong, I suppose it should be `fileURLWithPath:` in place of `fileURLWithString`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns nil because the URL is malformed. If you need more help, please post the exact string you put in there.

**Edit**

This is an example how to create a file URL, please note use of `initFileURLWithPath:`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:appPath];
```

Comment: @Eiko: Hey I have edited my quesion and posted my code there. Can you please check out that and tell me where it might be malforming the URL?

Comment: Edited to show the correct usage of NSURL for files. Just realized it's the same snippet as @Jordan gave. Just happened to be copy/paste from one of my projects.

Comment: @Eiko: My code does the same. The `filepath1` variable shows correct value of the path but the `[NSURL URLWithString:filepath1]` returns nil. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Eiko: Then what should I use to implement Lazy Table Image Loading?

Comment: What @Eiko used in his example code. It's a different method.

Comment: The method is called initFileURLWithPath.

Comment: I would just use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting the filePath correctly. Here's one way to do it.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newImage.jpg"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: myFilePath] autorelease];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:fileURL
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: You're leaking `fileURL`. Don't forget to release it when you are done with it.

Comment: yup - on the fly coding - added autorelease

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but seeing your code I noticed that the filePath1 is a NSString to which you are assigning the path of the image location in documents directory. But the string is not initialized anywhere, I mean don't u need to use `alloc` `initWithString:` or `stringWithString:`

Comment: But my string is not nil. it shows its proper value. but the [NSURL URLWithString:] returns nil. What could be wrong?